# Operations While Solving Equation Systems in $(\mathbb{R},+,.)$

Tags: systems-of-equations, real-numbers

It is easy to understand why we don't  do simplification in $(\mathbb{R},+, .)$ 
without having a good look at  while solving equation systems since $(\mathbb{R},+, .)$ is a domain. So I also know that multiplying equations with real numbers, or adding  one  to another is OK. But i can't figure out why my operations don't satisfy the system even if just do some multiplication and addition.

Let x and y be real numbers

$x^2+6y=36 $  $ $ $ $  $ $ $ $  $ $ $ $               (1)

$4x-y^2=49$       $ $ $ $  $ $ $ $  $ $ $ $    (2)

then $y^2-x^2=?$

***My Solution:***

multiplying (2) with -1

$x^2+6y=36$

$y^2-4x=-49$

then adding them together

$(x-2)^2 +(y+3)^2=0$

$x=2$ and $y=-3$ which are NOT satify the system.

It is easy to figure out that system have no solution in $\mathbb{R}$ since graphs of   (1) and (2) are two parabolas wihch don't intersect within any points.

[image: Figure]

I would be greatful if you explain that confusing matter, thanks in advance.

Comment: Because when you add together two equations, you must keep one of the previous too.

Comment: $x^2+6y-4x+y^2=36-4x+y^2$  then 


$x^2+6y-4x+y^2=36-49$ then 

$(x-2)^2+(y+3)^2=0$

i can't figure out why this doesn't satify